# Vectorising numpys roll

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm doing some sampling from an array at the moment, and I'm using a boolean mask to count the number of values that lay within a certain radius from a given centroid. I was wondering if someone could show me how to vectorise my approach instead of using a python loop to loop over elements of a list.

I have a 1d numpy array called centres, where each element of centres is a centroid given as a 1d numpy array. I have also created a boolean mask which is centered in the middle of the array ('centre_Y', 'centre_X' in the code below), which I am rolling from the middle of the array to the centroid position. I am then making the mask be sparse because my actual array that I am sampling from ('item' in the code below) is sparse. I then count the number of nonzero elements under the mask. Below is my code

```
for item in data:

    ### Do stuff

    for radius in radii:

        ### Do stuff

        # roll mask to centroid and count the number of elements within radius
        for centroid in centres:

            # roll in the vertical direction to centroid y coordinate
            mask_roll_y = np.roll(mask,centroid[0]-centre_Y,axis=0)

            # roll in the horizontal direction to centroid x coordinate and make sparse
            roll_mask = sparse.csr_matrix(np.roll(mask_roll_y,centroid[1]-centre_X,axis=1))

            # apply sparse mask to sparse data and count number of nonzero elements below
            number_count.append(np.count_nonzero(item[roll_mask]))
```

Now, the code above works perfectly fine and gives the results I want. My issue is, after doing some timings, the 'for centroid in centres' loop takes about .4 seconds to compute (for one array in data while using 50 radii and taking 100 samples for each radii), which is far and away the most time consuming part of my code. I need to do this for about 100 data sets with roughly 1000 arrays in each data set and I would like to take far more radii and samples than I did previously. So, I was wondering how I could eliminate the 'for centroid in centres' loop? I tried the following horrible piece of code

```
number_count.append(np.count_nonzero(item[sparse.csr_matrix(np.roll(np.roll(mask,centres[:][0]-centre_Y,axis=0),centres[:][1]-centre_X,axis=1))]))
```

where I tried to vectorise centres, but this just gave me a list of zeros in number count of length len(centres). Could anyone help please?

EDIT:

I forgot to specify that I need to roll my mask from the center to certain positions to maintain periodicity of the mask. Applying the mask straight away near the edges of the boolean array doesn't wrap the mask around to the parallel edge, and I don't want the mask to have a cutoff. This is because the data I am applying the mask to comes from a simulation with periodic boundary conditions.

UPDATE:

So I managed to write a piece of code using Numba that eliminated the need for masks and is quite fast. It takes in a 2d numpy array, a list of positions (centroids) to sample from and a radius to sample out to. The code iterates through the positions and searches for the nonzero elements within radius distance from each position. The boundaries are handled periodically. Some aspects of the code are redundant and I'm sure it can be made better and more general, but it works for what I need. Thanks to those who gave their input into the problem.

```
@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def nonzero_count(array,positions,radius):

    stored_values = list()
    y,x = array.shape

    for k in range(len(positions)):

        pos_y,pos_x = positions[k][0],positions[k][1]
        nonzero = 0

        # this section handles the periodic boundary conditions
        if pos_y+radius+1>y:
            # recenter pos_y so it is given a negative value
            aa = y-(pos_y+radius+1)
            # iterate around new pos_y, from -'ve to +'ve
            yy = (aa-radius,aa+radius+1)
        else:
            aa = pos_y
            yy = (pos_y-radius,pos_y+radius+1)

        if pos_x+radius+1>x:
            # recenter pos_x so it is given a negative value
            bb = x-(pos_x+radius+1)
            # iterate around new pos_x, from -'ve to +'ve
            xx = (bb-radius,bb+radius+1)
        else:
            bb = pos_x
            xx = (pos_x-radius,pos_x+radius+1)

        # this section handles the count
        for i in range(yy[0],yy[1]):
            for j in range(xx[0],xx[1]):
                # check nonzero elements lie within radius
                if array[i,j] != 0 and (bb-j)**2+(aa-i)**2<=radius**2:
                    nonzero += 1

        stored_values.append(nonzero)

    return stored_values
```

Comment: Are you sure the use of `sparse` helps you?  Even with a simple case `item[roll_mask]` is much slower than the equivalent using dense arrays.  Even on the fly conversion to array is faster, `item.A[roll_mask.A]`.

Comment: @hpaulj Sparse definitely helps when I have 200 or more data arrays of size 1024x1024 and bigger and there might only be on the order of 10^3 nonzero elements in each array. By using sparse arrays, I save myself about 1.6GB in memory when storing 200 1024x1024 arrays. I'll do some timings converting to dense and applying the mask and see what the difference is. However, I think the main issue slowing down the computation would be the python loop, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the `numba` package to speed up these loops, it seems it would be perfect for your use case. Just do something like the following, and some refactoring will most likely be required:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(nopython=True)
def slow_code():
    # roll in the vertical direction to centroid y coordinate
    mask_roll_y = np.roll(mask,centroid[0]-centre_Y,axis=0)

    # roll in the horizontal direction to centroid x coordinate and make sparse
    roll_mask = sparse.csr_matrix(np.roll(mask_roll_y,centroid[1]-centre_X,axis=1))

    # apply sparse mask to sparse data and count number of nonzero elements below
    number_count.append(np.count_nonzero(item[roll_mask]))

for item in data:

    ### Do stuff

    for radius in radii:

        ### Do stuff

        # roll mask to centroid and count the number of elements within radius

        for centroid in centres:
            slow_code()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried using the numba package a long time ago and had a whole heap of issues getting the wrapper to actually work, even after reading the documentation. I found it quite finicky. I'll give it a go now and see if it works, but I was hoping to get away without using the package. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: It can be finicky, but it can optimize your code (especially loops like this one) by orders of magnitude. You just will need to have an understanding of ctypes and the limitations that come with that.

Comment: I tried the numba package before with a slight modification to your code, by passing in the centers list, mask, center_Y, center_X and item as arguments to the slow_code function. It seems like it doesn't like the sparse arrays passed in as 'item' in my code, because I keep getting the following error: 'This error may have been caused by the following argument(s):
- argument 4: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>'

Comment: @Mattos I'm not sure if sparse matrices are supported, so if you need to use them this may not work...

Comment: I'll try converting item from sparse to full using .todense() and apply the mask on the full array using numba. I think I tried this the other day though and it didn't work. One last question. Is it possible to write my code using broadcasting of the sparse arrays? The one liner I wrote (down the bottom of my original post) broadcasts quite quickly, but count_nonzero only ever seems to return a vector of zeros for every radii so I wasn't sure what was going wrong. Also, thank you for all your help, I'll accept your answer now.

Comment: So I believe that numba supports broadcasting, however loops seem to be easier to debug should you run into problems. As far as what is supported you are probably best off reading the official documentation here: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html

Comment: Yeah, I've been through the documentation. I ended up getting the code working with Numba, but it ended up being _much_ slower than what I already have, probably due to the calls to numpy.roll (even though roll is supported with Numba). I'll add my Numba attempt in the original post. Unless I manage to write a loop which acts like numpy.roll, I doubt I will get anything better than what I currently have. Again, thanks for all your help.

Comment: Just so you know, I managed to rewrite the code entirely using Numba and it works very well. It's much faster than the rolling I was doing before. I also managed to speed up the rolling code I was using before by an order of magnitude, simply by converting the data array from sparse to dense and _not_ converting the mask to sparse. Again, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If your mask is sparse, it is better to first convert it to sparse and then roll it; this will give you significant speedups.  As you are doing it now, you are converting the matrix to sparse in the loop, which is both expensive and negates the advantages.

Observe:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sparse

zero_matrix = np.zeros((1024, 1024))
%timeit np.roll(zero_matrix, (10, 10))
>>1000 loops, best of 3: 1.36 ms per loop

sparse_matrix = sparse.random(1024, 1024, density = 0.001)
%timeit np.roll(sparse_matrix, (10, 10))
>>100000 loops, best of 3: 15.4 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is, rolling a sparse mask doesn't work. Using the code you gave above, the mask doesn't actually roll from it's original position to its new position. You can check this yourself by printing sparse_matrix and the rolled sparse_matrix. Also, if I specify which axis to roll along (like in my original post), I get an error 'AxisError: axis 0 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0' because the sparse matrix has no axis (as far as I can tell, I could be wrong). So I don't think works.

Comment: Good point, my apologies for not checking the code.  I wonder if you can "simulate" a sparse matrix by just storing the non-zero values in your own data structure.  When you are rolling you are essentially just shifting indices.  This should be quite fast.  There are also available functions that can roll a sparse matrix; see for example https://librosa.github.io/librosa/_modules/librosa/util/utils.html#roll_sparse

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'll take a look when I get a chance. Turns out that turning my mask sparse and applying it to the already sparse data set was about 10x slower than turning my sparse data set into a full array and applying then applying the full array mask to it. Hopefully I'll get Numba working and if I do, I'll update my original post with the new code so others might get some use from it.